# parse arguments with multiple multi words in bash

Tags: bash, parsing, arguments

Please find below simplified bash script parseArg.sh :-

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function parse(){

    local propsFile=$1


    echo "search file is : >$propsFile<"

    while IFS='=' read -r packageKey packageValue;
    do


        echo "package value is >$packageValue<"

        packageProcessor $packageValue

        echo "---------------------------------------------------------"
    done < "$propsFile"
}

function packageProcessor(){
    echo "Total args : $#"
    echo "All args value : >$@<"
    for arg in "$@"
    do
        echo "$arg"
    done
}

$@
```

Below is the configuration file repos.conf in same directory :-

```
cm5-centos6.6="https://archive.cloudera.com/cm5/redhat/6/x86_64/cm/5/ cm5-centos6.6 cm5/centos6.6 cm5/centos6.6 cm5-centos_6_6 "Cdh 5 for CentOS 6.6""
```

When I execute below command in same directory :-

> sh parseArg.sh parse repos.conf

I was expecting 6 arguments, but it gives total 10 arguments.
Below is the actual output :-

```
search file is : >repos.conf<
package value is >"https://archive.cloudera.com/cm5/redhat/6/x86_64/cm/5/ cm5-centos6.6 cm5/centos6.6 cm5/centos6.6 cm5-centos_6_6 "Cdh 5 for CentOS 6.6""<
Total args : 10
All args value : >"https://archive.cloudera.com/cm5/redhat/6/x86_64/cm/5/ cm5-centos6.6 cm5/centos6.6 cm5/centos6.6 cm5-centos_6_6 "Cdh 5 for CentOS 6.6""<
"https://archive.cloudera.com/cm5/redhat/6/x86_64/cm/5/
cm5-centos6.6
cm5/centos6.6
cm5/centos6.6
cm5-centos_6_6
"Cdh
5
for
CentOS
6.6""
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Oof, you'll need to find a more robust config file format. JSON or YAML perhaps.

Comment: @glennjackman : not sure, how easy will be parsing of yaml or json in bash. so thought of using configuration file in this format.

Comment: You also need to validate the command line arguments of your script: `sh parseArg.sh rm -rf .` will actually execute that `rm` command catastrophically: throw an error for "unknown subcommand: rm"

Answer (score 0):

In the `parse` function, the variable `packageValue` will contain a single string with the value:

```
"https://archive.cloudera.com/cm5/redhat/6/x86_64/cm/5/ cm5-centos6.6 cm5/centos6.6 cm5/centos6.6 cm5-centos_6_6 "Cdh 5 for CentOS 6.6""
```

The leading and trailing quotes are present in the variable's value. The quotes in that string are plain characters.

The only feasible way to parse this into 6 separate components would be to use `eval` to force the shell to respect the "inner" quotes. First you'd have to strip the leading and trailing quotes:

```
    tmp=${packageValue#\"}
    packageValue=${tmp%\"}
    packageProcessor "$packageValue"
```

Then, in the `packageProcessor` function, you would have to use `eval` to assign the string as an array, but you need to temporarily disable filename generation: you want to take advantage of word splitting, but not be affected by path expansion.

```
set -f
eval "elements=($1)"
set +f
```

Now you can

```
declare -p elements
for arg in "${elements[@]}"; do echo "$arg"; done
```

Having said all that, don't do it. This is inherently unsafe. Use a data storage format that does not expose you to unsafe calls to `eval` just to split your data.

If you are in complete control over the contents of that config file, use shell syntax to make it a script you can source:

```
declare -a cm5_centos_6_6=(https://archive.cloudera.com/cm5/redhat/6/x86_64/cm/5/ cm5-centos6.6 cm5/centos6.6 cm5/centos6.6 cm5-centos_6_6 "Cdh 5 for CentOS 6.6")
```

Comment: command "declare -p elements" emits output declare -a elements='([0]="https://archive.cloudera.com/cm5/redhat/6/x86_64/cm/5/" [1]="cm5-centos6.6" [2]="cm5/centos6.6" [3]="cm5/centos6.6" [4]="cm5-centos_6_6" [5]="Cdh 5 for CentOS 6.6")'. Is ther any way to disable this.

Comment: remove that line. I added it for debugging and to demonstrate success.

Comment: You're not heeding the "don't do it" advice, are you?

Comment: As per the business requirement, we have only three chioces to store configuration (json, xml or plain config file). I am not sure, how complex is to parse    json or xml in bash. So, we decided to go with plain config file. As of now, I am not very good at python. May be later on, when we include python, then we will move our configuration from plain config to xml.